# Change OS X partition to Mac OS Extended Journaled without reformatting?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, filesystems, operating-systems

I have a machine running OS X 10.5.8, and am upgrading it to Snow Leopard, and then Lion. Snow Leopard requires a Journaled partition, but the partition the OS is running on now is Mac OS Extended — no journaling.

Can I journal the partition without reformatting and losing data?

Comment: Nevermind, my stupid head missed the "Enable Journaling" button in Disk Utility. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. Easily. I had simply just missed the "Enable Journaling" button in Disk Utility, sixth from the left in the upper toolbar.

[image]